# PyCUDA test_cumath.py fails on cosh

Tags: python, numpy, pycuda, tesla

I've installed pycuda on a machine featuring a TESLA C2075. I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 with the CUDA-6.0 compiler installed.

Using python 2.7.9 (via the anaconda distribution) and numpy 1.9.0, I have installed pycuda 2014.1 from the ZIP file that Andreas Kloeckner provides on his website.
(http://mathema.tician.de/software/pycuda/)

Running the tests provided by that ZIP file goes all well except for the `test_cumath.py` file. I receive the following error:

```
E               AssertionError: (2.3841858e-06, 'cosh', <type 'numpy.complex64'>)`
E               assert <built-in method all of numpy.bool_ object at 0x7f00747f3880>()`
E                +  where <built-in method all of numpy.bool_ object at 0x7f00747f3880> = 2.3841858e-06 <= 2e-06.all

test_cumath.py:54: AssertionError`
===== 1 failed, 27 passed in 12.57 seconds =====
```

Does anyone have a suggestion where this discrepancy between the GPU and CPU result for cosh comes from? Being just slightly over the tolerance of 2e-6 with that measured value of 2.38e-6 looks a bit weird to me. Especially, since the other tests succeed...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the GPGPU/CUDA community it is indeed known that different hardware platforms and CUDA library versions might yield different results when using the same API. The differences are always small. So, there is some heterogeneity across platforms.

Indeed, this makes it tedious to write tests based on numerical results. The classification of *right* and *wrong* becomes less sharp and one must answer "what is good enough?". One might consider this crazy and in many cases problematic, or even faulty. I think this should not be disputed here.

What do you think, where did the `2e-6` tolerance come from in the first place? I'd say someone *tried* to find a trade-off between how much of a variance he/she thought is sufficiently correct and how much of a variance he/she *expected*, practically. In the CPU world `2e-6` is already *large*. Hence, here someone chose a *large* tolerance in order to account for an expected degree of heterogeneity among GPU platforms.

In this case, practically, it probably means that the tolerance has not been chosen to reflect the real-world heterogeneity of GPU platforms.

Having said this, the GPGPU community is also aware of the fact that an incredible amount of GPU cards is flaky (broken, basically). Before running serious applications, GPU cards *must* be exhaustively tested. Especially, a GPU card should produce reproducible results. Fluctuations are an indicator for a broken card. The Teslas usually are not affected as much as consumer cards, but even there we have seen it. Do you have a second GPU card of the same type? Does it produce the same results?

Either you identify your GPU card as "broken" (by comparison with other cards of the same type) or you should submit a bug report to PyCUDA and tell them about the tolerance that does not suffice.

Comment: Thanks. I have 4 Teslas at hand and I can reproduce the same number with all of them. I just wonder why the author of these tests (presumably Andreas Kloeckner himself) chooses a limit that fails on a 4-year old high-end GPU device...?

Comment: Possilby because your 4-year old high-end GPU device was super-expensive and is already out-of-date (ha, no offense, I used these, too). Really, this is pure speculation, but he likely develops on a single device and does not have a complex and expensive testing pool. That is, he actually *needs* your information, so provide it to him :-). Also, possibly there really *is* some bug that can be revealed by communicating your observations to him.

Comment: Thanks for the prod, I've sent it to the mailing list and it has already been updated in the git repository of PyCUDA ;-)
No offense taken on the already out-of-date equipment, I have the chance to re-test it on K20s and K40s (less out-of-date at least :P ). I'll be back with results on that :-)